# LocalDateTime is converted to OffsetDateTime in client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, generate

This is my code to send to the client:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = FormatConstants.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT)
private LocalDateTime finalizationDate;
```

when i generate client with `swagger`,`apicodegen`

it creates jar for our customer and that variable becomes this:

```
  @SerializedName("finalizationDate")

  private OffsetDateTime finalizationDate = null;
```

Why this can be? What can i do? Should i convert our variable to also `offsetdatetime?`